# Delete one picture

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to delete one picture msword using macro

The sample code is below, I am new with but not working

```
Dim myImage As Shape

Set myImage = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1")

myImage.Delete
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet` is the Excel Object Model, not Word.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveSheet` is Excel, not Word. You would use `ActiveDocument` for Word and your picture may either be a `Shape` or an `InlineShape` depending on whether it has text wrapping or not.

```
Sub DeletePicture()
   ActiveDocument.Shapes("Picture 1").Delete
   ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: runtime error. The item with the specified name not found.
how to get the name of it?
I used the selection pane to get name

Comment: @YousufAliShahJeelani - all the relevant information is in my answer. It is up to you to work out whether the picture you want to delete is a `Shape` or an `InlineShape` and choose the correct line of code to run.